# Is there any way to pass javascript value to php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, content-management-system

I'm working on Magento CMS. Now i've want to pass javascript value to php to get sku, price,.,etc.

Here is my sample code,

```
        if(sizeOfExistingProducts==1)
        {
            alert(currentSimpleProductId)
            alert("<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load()->getSku(); ?>")
        }
```

Here, i've want to pass 'currentSimpleProductId' into load().

Need help plz. Thank in advance.

Comment: You can't do that, you need to make an AJAX request.

Comment: Server side can plug in the text data, then when the page is downloaded it can go to the client. Also only open the PHP processor at the top of the page for a best speed practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't, unless you load php code with ajax. The reason is, your php code is compiled at `server` before your browser runs your javascript code.